# How can I do unit testing in Perl?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing

I have been doing some OO Perl programming and I was wondering: which is the best way to perform unit tests?

So far I have been using the [Test::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Simple) module to perform tests, but it feels 
insufficient for what I want.

Can you point me to some nice modules for that?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I'd add my vote to picking up [`Test::More`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More) before going any further in Perl testing. The [Perl testing community](http://web.archive.org/web/20180628054858/http://perl-qa.hexten.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is fairly well united around the [Test Anything Protocol](http://testanything.org/), and you'll want to play around with [`Test::More`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More) to understand how it works and how tools like [`prove`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Harness/bin/prove) and `Test::Harness::Archive` can help automate and distribute testing.

If you want to just "jump right in", I think [`Test::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Class) provides xTest facilities with a [TAP](http://testanything.org/) backend. I haven't used it at all (I'm a [`Test::More`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More) person myself), but it's [very highly rated](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/Test-Class).

Comment: Great introduction, thanks!  I'm used to doing unit tests for python and php, but will be involved in a perl project soon, your post definitely helps me get started :)

Answer (score 19):

Test::More should offer you more bang for your bucks once you get the hang of Test::Simple.

Comment: I'm looking for something for close to JUnit or NUnit with a setup and tear down method etc... got any idea?

Answer (score 12):

Judging by your comments on melaos answer, I'd say [Test::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Class) or [Test::Unit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Unit) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Test::Unit is pretty much abandoned as of 2016 -  http://perlunit.sourceforge.net/ says "as recently as 2011..".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876091/what-is-the-preferred-unit-testing-framework-for-perl/39605597#39605597

Answer (score 11):

Simple test example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use Test::More plan => 4;  # or use Test::More 'no_plan';

use_ok('My::Module', 'Loaded My::Module');
ok( my $obj = My::Module->new(), 'Can create instance of My::Module');

ok( $obj->value('hello'), 'Set value to hello' );
is( $obj->value => 'hello', 'value is still hello');
```

Answer (score 3):

[Test::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::Class) usage you can see in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499967/programmatically-determining-the-longest-similar-portion-of-several-strings/500518#500518).