# How to test a CPAN package that requires having user credentials

Tags: perl, unit-testing, automated-tests

I'm in the process of making a module that I plan to distribute on CPAN that is a client library for a public API.

The API requires API credentials (client_id/secret), and I'm not sure what the best practice is in regards to running Perl tests for a distribution with such credentials.

Do I:

- Create a dummy account with the API and hope that others don't mess with it?
- Mock the requests and responses? <- Not in favour of this, as I don't think that it's a good idea to mock HTTP transactions for a API client library
- Not test... :S

Comment: Have you written some tests yet? If not, have you seen [this question on the preferred test framework for perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876091/what-is-the-preferred-unit-testing-framework-for-perl)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have the tests expect the credentials in environment variables (or if they are long or complicated, a config file). When the credentials are not provided, have the test issue a warning with instructions about performing the tests with credentials.

```
 use Test::More;

 unless ($ENV{MY_ID} && $ENV{MY_PWD}) {
     BAIL_OUT "*** This module requires credentials. Pass them in the
           MY_ID and MY_PWD environment variables, like 

                 MY_ID=username MY_PWD=passwd make test";
 }
```

Automated test systems (such as what many CPANTesters use) will never configure a module before it is tested, so the `BAIL_OUT` registers the test result on CPAN Testers as an "N/A" as opposed to a fail.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that this is a good idea to BAIL_OUT for common tests, run automatically by cpan-testers and on module installation.

I think you should just move your test into `xt` directory (authors test), which will be run only by you. And yes, best way to transfer credentials is via `ENV`, as **mob** suggested.